# Finding the mistake in induction proof

Tags: induction, fake-proofs

This argument seems obviously wrong, but I can't find the mistake. Any ideas?

> There are two people, each given a positive integer, such that the two integers differ by $1$. The rule of the game
>   requires that if anyone knows that if his number is the smallest among the two, then he should put up his hand. We
>   are going to prove that the one with the smaller number will always put up his hand.
>
> Suppose the two people are
>   given positive integers $n$ and $n + 1$. We shall prove that the one given the integer $n$ will put up his hand. Note that
>   this is true for $n = 1$ since $1$ is the smallest positive integer, so the one given the number $1$ must know that his number
>   is the smaller of the two.
>
> Suppose the statement holds for some $n$ and that the two people are given $n + 1$ and $n + 2$.
>
> The one with $n + 1$ will think
>   “the other number is either $n$ or $n + 2$.” Suppose that it is $n$. Then, by induction hypothesis, the other person should
>   put up his hand. But he doesn’t, so the other number must be $n + 2$.
>
> Consequently, the one with $n + 1$ will put up his hand.

Comment: This seems to be related to the "proof" that every positive integer is "interesting" , which works as follows : Suppose, not all positive integers are interesting. Then, there is a smallest non-interesting positive integer which makes this integer interesting.

Comment: The one with n + 1 will think “the other number is either n or n + 2. Suppose that it is n. Then, by induction hypothesis, the other person should put up his hand. But he doesn’t, so the other number must be n + 2.” Why ? Why the other must know that the first does not have $n-1$ ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Because $n+1$ and $n-1$ don't differ by $1$.

Comment: But how "the other" knows that the pair is $(n,n+1)$ and not $(n-1,n)$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The induction is not valid as it is not well defined. What I mean, is that the "waiting time" need not be the same all the time.

For example, under the assumption that a person takes 1 second to raise his hand, if player B had the number 2, he would wait 1 second, and if his partner does not raise his hand, then he will raise his. The same reasoning applies if he had the number $n$. If a person does not raise his hand after $n-1$ seconds, then it would be clear that he would not have the number $n-1$.

However, this is not the case in your problem, generating a kind of paradox similar to [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unexpected_hanging_paradox). Again, the problem here is that in your proof it should say "Then, by induction hypothesis, the other person should put up his hand  after $X$ time. But he doesn’t." As you do not define $X$, you get that paradoxical result.

Comment: Time has nothing to do here.

Answer (score 3):

The base case is proven for the numbers $1$ and $2$ (denoted $n$ and $n+1$).

The induction works with $n+1$ and $n+2$ instead, hence the base case should correspond to $\color{red}{n=0}$. Then the statement 'The one with $n+1$ will think "the other number is either $\color{red}n$ or $n+2$"' does not hold.

This is a variant of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_horses_are_the_same_color.